# How to run multiple command in one task by vscode and how to set in which terminal will the task execute?

Tags: command-line, powershell, visual-studio-code

Ok, I am using VsCode(visual studio code). and I want to create a task where I can run two or more than two commands after running one task. for example:

if I want to use `node` command and after running this command I wanna use `5+6`

then I wanna create a task that will do both of them by running one task.

And I also want to know how can I say that run `some tasks` in `Command Prompt` or `PowerShell` or something else. So these are my questions. I searched about them on google before but I couldn't understand them well. So I want to know a good answer :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/32290053/7411885 - It uses bash/python instead of powershell/node, but the result is the same. Use powershell or cmd as your task runner, then use node or other tools as powershell commands.